# Mobile Associates API & Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.ios, in-app, amazon-in-app-purchase

I want to do something really simple: in my mobile App the users can Link something they're selling on Amazon. I want to include in my App a "button" that redirect to Amazon to buy the item and earn the 6% of the Mobile Associates API..

BUT my app is written in Xamarin..

Does anybody knows how to integrate the "Mobile Associate API" in a Xamarin APP? Is there any way to get the link without the Mobile Associate API? Something like open a Link in a browser with a parameter in Query String or a Token as Authentication?

Answer (score 0):

You can integrate any native Android library into your Xamarin Android app by creating a [Binding Library](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/java_integration_overview/binding-a-java-library/) for it.